# GDAL error - no create method for format - QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am trying to clip a raster layer. I am getting the error..

ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.

The documentation (link below) says to use GeoTIFF (gtiff). The format GeoTIFF exists, but the extensions are .tif .tiff .TIF & .TIFF.

What am I missing?

[gdal.org/gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

Edit:
Raster > Extraction > Clipper... Select a region. Give it a name. Hit OK. Note the tiff file types available.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It feels like something else is happening. GeoTIFF driver for sure supports create method but GDAL seems to think that some other driver is requested. Can you give more details about your workflow?

Comment: Can you provide full command line or steps in QGIS to reproduce?

Comment: If you look at your 1st screenshot, the `-of AIG` argument in the `gdal_translate` command line shows the output format has been specified as ESRI ArcInfo Binary GRID. This driver does not have a create method, it's read-only.

Comment: I can't reproduce in QGIS 2.16. But I'm running it on Linux, not Windows. The only way I can get AIG as the output format is to manually edit the `gdal_translate` command line in the clipper dialog.

Comment: I am having the same issue however my command line does not have the -aig. See attached screenshot. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpsRml.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpsRml.jpg)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line in your first screen shot contains `-of AIG`. This flag overrides the `.tif` extension of the output filename.

According to http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#AIG, this format is read-only.

You might have run into a bug when the file type in the file dialogue does not fit to the filename, or does not get updated correctly. Since you want a Geotiff file, explicitely choose the .tif format, and check if the flag has been corrected in the command line box. By clicking on the pencil next to it, you can change it to edit mode, and change the output format identifier manually.

I can't reproduce your error here, but it might just be a stored preset from another task you did before. https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15285 seems to be a similar case.

Comment: Yes, that was it. And it actually insisted I specify the GTiff as the format. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation. I opened the clip raster by extent in processing tool box. I entered the input raster data and manually entered the extent. 
I specified the parameters like no data value, output type (byte: in my case) and compression (LZW) and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had your same problem and I have solved just saving the clip in a different folder of the main raster file.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your answer to include more detail about how you solved the issue - some steps to replicate your solution.